# Fabricjs animation bound to slider

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

we are developing an editor that can create animations on images placed on a canvas. Thanks to Fabric.js everything went smooth for drawing the images, resizing, drag-drop, etc...
Now we are trying to create the animations by binding the animation time to a slider.

Example:
- Object A moves from x1 to y1 between second 0 and 10
- Object B moves from x2 to y2 between second 1 and 5
When the users places the slider on position 3, both objects are somewhere in the middle of their animation.

Any tips or tricks on how to accomplish this?

I have a little code sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/ewxx1Lqe/

```
var fabricCanvas;
var ballImage;
var playing = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#animationSlider").slider({        
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        value: 0
    });
    fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("field", {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,128,0)'
    });

     ballImage = fabric.Image.fromURL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg",     function (img) {
        img.width = 20;
        img.height = 20;
        img.left = 10;
        img.top = 10;
        img.hasControls = false;
        fabricCanvas.add(img);
        fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(img);
    });

    $("#btnPlay").click(function(){
        playing = true;
         fabric.util.animate({
            startValue: fabricCanvas.getActiveObject().get('left'),
            endValue: fabricCanvas.getActiveObject().get('left') + 200,
            duration: 5000,
            onChange: function (value) {
                fabricCanvas.getActiveObject().setLeft(value);
               fabricCanvas.renderAll();
            },
            onComplete: function () {
                fabricCanvas.getActiveObject().setCoords();
            },
            abort: function () {
                return !playing;
            }
        });
    }); 
    $("#btnPause").click(function(){
        playing = false;
    });
});
```

While playing the animation the slider should slide to the according seconds. And vice versa, when sliding the slider, the ball should animate.

Comment: Can you post relevant code samples of what you have working so far?

Comment: @MariM I edited my question with some sample code and according JSFiddle.